# NSLocalizedString: confusion with short string - substring

Tags: objective-c, xcode, translation, nslocalizedstring

In my code I use a lot of localized strings and all works great, except with short strings.

Example

```
NSString* text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%@ at %@", nil), dateStart, timeStart];
```

In file **localizable.string** I have:

```
"%@ at %@" = "<translation>"
"attending %@" = "<translation>"
```

In my opinion, compiler fails when try to get the right string.. how can I achieve this?

Comment: First of all what is wrong? Second, are you sure file called localizable.string? It doesn't seem right to me.

Answer (score -1):

The left side is the key for the copy on the right side.
It's not the key that should have the placeholders in it, as the string is exchanged at runtime by the string from the locale.strings.
In other words: after localization you are missing the `%@`

To achieve what you want, you need the placeholders to be in the translated string:

```
"SOME_KEY" = "%@ <localized> %@"
```

Comment: You can you use whatever you want in keys.

Comment: That is correct, thanks for pointing out. But the issue in the question is that the %@ is replaced by localization